# Replace a string in all the pages with php

Tags: php, file, server

I searched the stack overflow and couldn't find an answer. What I want to do is that I want to replace all the links to switch from http:// to https:// .
My public_html contains many folders and files and they also contains more folder and files and so on.

**Edit:** Also I don't have shell access. I did read some answers but they all used SSH.
I cannot download the code so it has to be PHP. Thank you.

Comment: How would you switch the links if you cannot download the code?

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way to visit directories and open files and replace links. @FelippeDuarte

Comment: File search and replace is the only lasting option. As *temporary* workound: [`Substitute "s~http://~https://~ni"`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html). Questions should elaborate on other attempts/[research](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+rewrite+html+links+http:+to+https:) and not just rejected options.

Comment: If you can't download, upload, or ssh, how would you modify the website's code normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tip: You can turn on force https but that would only work for your server and not for any external resources you download.*

This code will replace *http:* with *https:* . That's because any prior occurrence of *https* would result in *httpss*, that's why the ':' at the end.

```
<?php
function replacehttp($dir){
    $dir_array = scandir($dir);
    unset($dir_array[array_search('.', $dir_array, true)]);
    unset($dir_array[array_search('..', $dir_array, true)]);
    if (count($dir_array) < 1)
        return;
    foreach($dir_array as $temp){
        if(is_file($dir.'/'.$temp))
        {
         $file_contents = file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$temp);
         $file_contents = str_replace("http:","https:",$file_contents);
         //replacing http: with https: because replacing "http" with "https" would result in existing "https" string to become "httpss"
         file_put_contents($dir.'/'.$temp,$file_contents);  
        }
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$temp)) replacehttp($dir.'/'.$temp);
    }
}
replacehttp(getcwd()); //Works in the current directory the php file is placed in or add full path to the directory.
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, let me check. @Hackinet